# $cordovaMedia stop working

Tags: android, angularjs, audio, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a musical instrument consisting of eight notes, these notes are represented by an image divided into eight areas.
Whenever I press area plays a note, if I press repeatedly several areas after a while the app stops producing sounds.
How can I avoid that happening?

Now I post some code... I working with Ionic Framework.

in app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'starter.controllers'])
```

and so on...
but the interested part of app.js is the callback of 'ngCordova' into angular.module

now on controllers.js

`

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('SoundCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaMedia) {
  //Play a media
  $scope.play = function(src) {
    var media = new Media(src, null, null);
    $cordovaMedia.play(media);
  };
})
```

`

finally on my file html I do this

```
        `

<img src="img/image.png" style="margin-top:10%;width:100%;height:auto;" usemap="#hangdrum">
            <map name="hangdrum">
                <area shape="circle" coords="298,63,37,34" ng-click="play('/android_asset/www/mp3/A.mp3')">
```

`

now... the sound is ok and it start correctly but if I play this sound (or press this  different times after 10 time (more or less) it stop to play sound.

Why? How can I fix it?
Thanks to all ;)

Comment: I solved it with a ngCordova plugin cordovaNativaAudio

Comment: Could you please help me? I am getting `Media is not defined` error.